# Integrate Laravel Nova with current API Controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I has an API system built on Laravel, and everything has been running good for 1 year. Now I want to create an Admin Panel, and decided to go with Nova.

I tried to read the document and research on Google, but couldn't find an example to integrate Nova with our current system. We already have complicated controllers, helpers, rules... setup in API controllers, so I can't just rewrite all of them with Nova field and tools because it would take forever.

For example: we upload a video via API post -> custom validate video size, length, format -> save to S3 -> create a new data row in 1 table and update data in 1 other table, simultaneously.

So how can I reuse this flow from a Nova image upload field? And this is just 1 step in the multiple steps of user interactions.

I know I might lost it somewhere in the docs, because I'm new to Nova, so please help me with this.

Thank you.